# Can't render JSON results in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to loop through the nested JSON object returned from searching the Spotify REST API, but unable to render the results.

Within my controller:

```
function fetch() {
  $http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + $scope.search + "&type=artist&limit=50")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.artists.items);
      $scope.details = response.data.artists.items;
    });
}
```

which returns an object that looks like this:[image]

I'm trying to loop through the response with this:

```
<div ng-if="details.response==='True'">
  <ul ng-repeat="song in details">
    <li>Songs:{{song.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and display the `external_urls` value, `images` urls, as well as the `name` value. However, none of these are being rendered (not even the word `Songs` which should be showing regardless of whether or not I have the correct values).

Comment: Your problem is in the ng-if clause, your evaluating as a boolean that is not behaving as such, you need to declare a boolean value that becomes true when the response holds data. This is also the reason why you can't see the word Songs, the div is simply not showing because it's being evaluated to a value it can't interpret

Comment: ... to be specific, your `details` doesn't contain a `response`, it contains an array of `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ng-if` clause

Have it evaluate to an actual `boolean` that becomes true when the response has data.

Something like:

```
.then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.artists.items);
      $scope.isTheDataLoaded = true;
      $scope.details = response.data.artists.items;
```

And in your html:

```
<div ng-show="isTheDataLoaded">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to

```
<div ng-if="details">
    <ul ng-repeat="song in details">
        <li>Songs:{{song.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Because "details" doesn't contain "response". So you just have to check if it exists or if it's not empty